# Is it possible to play ARK with two PS4 on LAN?

Tags: ps4, ark-survival-evolved

In case that [my other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376304/how-many-ps-subscriptions-do-we-need-to-play-on-a-private-server-over-the-inter) gets answered with **more than 1** and we need some PS+ accounts in order to play on *our own server* over the Internet, we want to know, if it's possible to play the game over LAN, without having to get a PS+ subscription. Again I've searched the web, but only found information on how to achieve this on PC (e.g. using command line parameters on executables), but not on PS4.

Our goal is to play with 2 consoles on 2 TVs in the same apartment, so we don't have to use the split screen method. We don't want to get a PS+ subscription and therefore want to play offline over LAN.

**Is it possible to play *Ark: Survival Evolved* entirely over LAN (dedicated/non-dedicated) on Playstations? If yes, how so?**

Comment: I would like to clear some stuff up here. LAN is NOT online. LAN is "Local Area Network". Which means you do not need a PSN account for this. All you need is an ethernet chord and you will be good. This is with most games that support multiplayer - not just free to play games. This is not a bug that will be patched, this is how networking works in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the details about general online play requirements can be found at [this help page from Sony](https://support.playstation.com/s/article/PS4-Online-Multiplayer-Requirements?language=en_US).

Only free-to-play games can be played online without a PS+ subscription. Otherwise, at least one account in the console must have a subscription to PS+, and that account must have that playstation marked as its primary console in order for online play to be enabled in that console. As long as you have that, all other accounts in the console will be able to play online even if they don't have a subscription.

I have done some fiddling with both a PS4 and a PS4 pro, and I believe the PS+ subscription check is done online when the system boots. Failure to connect to PSN marks seems to disable online play until PSN can be reached again.

So to summarize: you can hook two playstations in a LAN for the smallest latency possible between them, but that's the only advantage you get. You still need at least two PS+ subscriptions to play online, and must be able to connect to PSN anyway. The only exception is if the games you wish to play are free-to-play.

---

Since you are asking specifically about Ark, you should also check that game's page at the Playstation Store if you bought it online, or the game's case if you have the physical copy. In both cases you will find this:

> Online multiplayer (2-70 players). A paid-for PlayStation Plus membership is required.

And later on:

> One-time license fee for play on account’s designated primary PS4™ system and other PS4™ systems when signed in with that account.

Comment: since the user mentioned LAN, just wanted to add that some non free-to-play games can be played over LAN without a PS Plus subscription, Borderlands: The Handsome Colleciton is the only example I know of though.

Comment: @ZekeHernandez that must be a bug that could be patched at some point, [as the store page for that mentions you need an account to play online too](https://store.playstation.com/en-ca/product/UP1001-CUSA01401_00-BORDERLANDSHDCOL) (under the game price).

Comment: So it's not possible. Too bad. I was hoping that it would work like Battlefield 2, where you play on charged online servers provided by the publisher (or Sony) or on a free local server. Guess I'm not up to date, aynmore ^^° So the only way to play together without paying would be to play in split screen mode?

Comment: @tim with your setup, yes. But you've already paid what, 600+ dollars on consoles plus 70 to 140 dollars on the game, and now you don't want to pay 22 dollars for a couple 1-month subscriptions... Why don't you just subscribe for a month, see if you like it? You don't have to keep the subscriptions if you get tired of it after a month. Also I think Sony offers a free trial for first timers.

Comment: Alright. Now it's all clear to me, thanks. Btw I got console and game for about 350, and I'm a cheapskate who likes to fiddle around, saving money ^^ I would've set up a VPN for my friend and me to play over "LAN", if it would've been possible. Guess we'll be utilizing the trial period and maybe subscribe afterwards then.

Comment: @Renan It's not a bug, it's literally a menu item that you can choose and it just works. I tried it not that long ago, long after the game was released, so I doubt they would patch it out. As LAN is not "online" that PS Plus requirement wouldn't necessarily be in effect.

Comment: I can only personally confirm Borderlands the Handsome Collection, but after briefly searching online I've seen Black Ops 3, Dying Light, Saints Row: Gat out of Hell all mentioned as games that support LAN multiplayer.